# Python: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). How to Debug?

Tags: python, crash, python-3.7

I'm getting a strange error "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" running python 3.7 on a windows machine. The process just crashes. The error comes in random time.  It seems to appear inside a thread.

Is there someway to get more information where exactly the error comes from? Right now my only solution is to add logging, but that is really time consuming.

Thanks a lot for any hint.

Comment: Did you find a way to debug this problem?

Comment: @TimWoocker actually there is no way to debug it, since the process just crashed. But you may get some infos in the system event logs. That helped in my case.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Could I ask you what you were trying to code? Maybe I'm lucky and I have the same problem you had.
So basically I'm running some code using ctypes but once I introduce another thread, the program crashes. Even if one thread does nothing (so they aren't doing any actions at the same time). Maybe there is a chance you had a similar problem

Comment: To be honest. Cant remember it but it was caused by a bad package. Had that issues multiple times. So you may have to find out which package causes problems

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, not long time ago and I have solved this with the following solution:

reinstall python – you don't have python33.dll in c:\WINDOWS\system32\

Maybe you have different python versions – look at folders in root of c:

If yes, then point to your version of python.exe in pyCharm > Settings > Project Interpreter

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this error occur when a Python script has infinite (or very deep) recursion and the following code is used to increase the recursion limit:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(4000)
```

I would guess that the error means we are running out of memory.

Comment: Yep, I think you are right, and the error code comes from infinite recursion leading to memory issues.